# How can I retrieve a csv from a server with http authentication in R?

Tags: r, wget, read.csv

I would normally do:

`read.csv(pipe("wget -O- stdout http://someServer/aFile.csv"))`

But in this case the wget command that works is this one:

```
wget -O- stdout http://someServer/aFile.csv --user=foo --ask-password
```

This prompts for a password before working. If I pass this to `pipe` it hangs, is there a workaround that wouldn't require clear typing the password?

Comment: look at `httr`; specifically the `GET()` function with `write_file()` and `authenticate()` parameters

Comment: This authentication parameter in the documentation seems to take the password in clear text too though...

Comment: it stays in-process, though (unlike the `wget` call). If you have the "encrypted" password (basic auth is horribad and worthless if not over ssl/tls) pre-created, you can just insert it manually with `add_headers()`

Comment: I suppose if that's the best option I can abstract it into a function call that requires the password as an argument and disable Rhistory :/

Comment: honestly, if the server isn't using ssl/tls it really doesn't matter one bit. basic auth uses base64 encoding. there's no encryption happening at all. anyone looking over the wire (which is more than folks think) has your creds.